# Как в GridView выделить один из элементов

Tags: java, android

Делал календарь, выводящий даты по неделям.

**CalendarView.java**:

```
public class CalendarView extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener{

    private GridView                        mGrid;
    private View                            mConvertView;
    private GregorianCalendar               mCalendar;
    private Date[]                          mWeek;
    private Context                         mContext;
    private TextView                        mMonthText;
    private SimpleDateFormat                mFormatMonth;
    private SimpleDateFormat                mFormatDay;
    private SimpleDateFormat                mFormatYear;
    private OnDispatchDateSelectListener    mListenerDateSelect;
    private Button                          mArrowRight;
    private Button                          mArrowLeft;
    private CalendarAdapter                 mAdapter;
    public interface OnDispatchDateSelectListener {
        public void onDispatchDateSelect(Date date);
    }
    public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext            = context;
        mFormatMonth        = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        mFormatDay          = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
        mFormatYear         = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

        mConvertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.calendar, this);
        mGrid=(GridView)mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_days);

        mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mMonthText=(TextView)mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_month);
        mArrowLeft=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calendar_arrow_left);
        mArrowLeft.setOnClickListener(this);

        mArrowRight=(Button)mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_arrow_right);
        mArrowRight.setOnClickListener(this);

        mCalendar = (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.setTime(new Date());
        mCalendar.getInstance().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

        Integer dayDifference = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1 ? -6 : (Calendar.MONDAY - mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayDifference);



        mWeek=new Date[7];
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            mWeek[i]=mCalendar.getTime();
            mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        setSelectedMonthText();
        mAdapter=new CalendarAdapter(mContext, mWeek, Math.abs(dayDifference));

        mGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);



        mAdapter.getView(0, mConvertView, null).performClick();


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

        clearBackground();
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
        mListenerDateSelect.onDispatchDateSelect(mWeek[arg2]);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.calendar_arrow_left:
                subWeek();
            break;
            case R.id.calendar_arrow_right:
                addWeek();
            break;
        }
    }


    private void clearBackground()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<mGrid.getCount();i++)
        {
            mGrid.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }



    private void setSelectedMonthText()
    {
        String monthText;
        if(Integer.parseInt(mFormatDay.format(mWeek[0]))>Integer.parseInt(mFormatDay.format(mWeek[6])))
            monthText=mFormatMonth.format(mWeek[0])+" / "+mFormatMonth.format(mWeek[6]);
        else
            monthText=mFormatMonth.format(mWeek[0]);

        mMonthText.setText(monthText+" "+mFormatYear.format(mWeek[6]));
    }

    public void setOnDispatchDateSelectListener(OnDispatchDateSelectListener v) {
        mListenerDateSelect = v;
    }

}
```

**CalendarAdapter.java**:

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context             mContext;
    private Date[]              mWeek;
    private SimpleDateFormat    mFormatNumber;
    private SimpleDateFormat    mFormatDay;
    private LayoutInflater      mInflater;
    private int                 numberDay;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context _context, Date[] _week, int numberday) {
            mContext        = _context;
            mWeek           = _week;
            mFormatNumber   = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
            mFormatDay      = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
            mInflater       = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            numberDay = numberday;
    }


    //походу хранит в себе поля для ввода.
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView     tvDay;
        public TextView     tvNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mWeek.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    //Здесь происходит формирование листа.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        //если неделя заполняется первый раз выполняется
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView     = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day, null);
            holder          = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvDay    = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_day);
            holder.tvNumber = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvDay.setText(mFormatDay.format(mWeek[position]));
        holder.tvNumber.setText(mFormatNumber.format(mWeek[position]));


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Собственно вопрос: как в конструкторе `CalendarView` вызвать метод `performClick()` для того, чтобы текущая дата сразу отображалась как активная?

Comment: Для выделения позиции вам нужно использовать метод [setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setSelection(int)), а не "принудительного" клика.

Comment: Алгоритм, который должен выполняться находится в обработчике. 
Нужно именно имитировать клик на элементе списка.